# nginx ""Address already in use""

Tags: python, nginx, grpc

Here is my proto file:

```
syntax="proto3";

service JsonJson {
    rpc CollectData(stringv_) returns (stringv_) {}
}


message stringv_ {
    string text=2;

}
```

Here is the part of the server code:

```
server=grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2))
jsonfy_pb2_grpc.add_JsonJsonServicer_to_server(JsonJsonServicer(),server)
#print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

Here is the part of the client code:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051/')
stub=jsonfy_pb2_grpc.JsonJsonStub(channel)
send_=jsonfy_pb2.stringv_(text="Bohnny")
response=stub.CollectData(send_)
try:
    print(json.loads(response.text))
except:
    print(response.text)
```

It runs completely fine whenever i don't use any api gateway.
Then i tried to use nginx as the api gateway. I changed the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to this:

```
upstream grpcservers {
                server 0.0.0.0:80;
        }
server {
                listen 50051 http2;
                listen [::]:50051 ipv6only=on default;

                location / {
                        grpc_pass grpc://grpcservers;
                }
        }
```

Then i run `sudo nginx -t` and it says nginx.conf is okay.Then i run `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. It runs without any error. After that whenever i run the main grpc server mentioned above it shows:

```
E0727 23:02:25.499389448    5913 server_chttp2.cc:40]        {"created":"@1595869345.499350541","description":"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.cc","file_line":397,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595869345.499348103","description":"Failed to add any wildcard listeners","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_posix.cc","file_line":344,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595869345.499335832","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":7,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":217,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595869345.499333004","description":"Address already in use","errno":98,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":190,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]},{"created":"@1595869345.499347440","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":7,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":217,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595869345.499345297","description":"Address already in use","errno":98,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":190,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]}]}]}
```

I am quite sure i am missing some important steps . Experts please enlighten me.I am just a newbie and trying to move away from rest to grpc. I use python.
This is what i found on /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: bind() to 0.0.0.0:50051 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: bind() to 0.0.0.0:50051 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: bind() to 0.0.0.0:50051 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: bind() to 0.0.0.0:50051 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: bind() to 0.0.0.0:50051 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/07/27 20:47:05 [emerg] 783#783: still could not bind()
2020/07/27 21:08:12 [emerg] 1541#1541: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
2020/07/27 23:08:20 [emerg] 6143#6143: "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2
2020/07/27 23:38:47 [emerg] 6745#6745: "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2
```

Comment: Sounds like the port is already used, or an instance or nginx is already running.  What does `syslog` say?

Comment: Also, after running `sudo service nginx start` run: `sudo service nginx status` and this will show if the service is actually running, or if there was a error on startup.

Comment: @S3DEV i ran  ``` sudo service nginx status ``` 
Service is running fine

Comment: This is the output: ```    CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─8248 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─8250 nginx: worker process
           ├─8252 nginx: worker process
           ├─8254 nginx: worker process
           └─8256 nginx: worker process

জুলাই 28 00:28:07 zaowad-pc systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
জুলাই 28 00:28:07 zaowad-pc systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server. ```

Comment: ``` sudo service nginx start ``` works fine . But the error occurs when i run ``` python server.py ``` after that. I guess i need to make some change in server.py file. Please check out the server code. @S3DEV

Comment: Perhaps change the port number.